# cabal cabal-install error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install, ghc-mod

I followed the procedure [here](https://gist.github.com/wting/8498731#option-ghc-784--cabal) for installing GHC and cabal, and then for ghc-mod.

But, I get this error at this step

```
cabal update && cabal install cabal-install
```

> Configuring cabal-install-1.24.0.2... Failed to install
>   cabal-install-1.24.0.2 cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   cabal-install-1.24.0.2 failed during the configure step. ExitFailure
>   11

Answer (score 0):

If you install `haskell-platform` via `apt-get`, version of `ghc` is under `7.10.3` until yakkety (Ubuntu 16.10).

This is problematic because `cabal-1.24` requires `ghc >= 8.0.1`.

To solve this

1. install more recent version of `ghc` from its [code](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/tree/ghc-8.0),
2. just use `stack` and `ghc-mod` for `stack`.

P.S. if you are emacsen, I recommand you to use `intero` ([site](https://commercialhaskell.github.io/intero/)) instead of `ghc-mod`.